# Use GStreamer to rename a file once it's done

Tags: gstreamer

Suppose I have a file that's called `my-video-file.mp4` and i want to use a gstreamer pipeline on it and save the result to a different file. Now, running the pipeline on it, typically what one would do is to provide a pipeline like `... ! filesink location=my-video-file-processed.mp4`
This streams the result directly into `my-video-file-processed.mp4`, which I don't like because it's not immediately clear to a user that the file is being processed. The user has to check if the filesize is increasing to see if it's still being processed.

Therefore, what I'd like to do is streaming it to a temporary file e.g. `my-scaled-video-file.mp4.temp` and have an additional pipeline-step where the file is renamed once it's done being processed to `my-video-file-processed.mp4`. This is similar to how e.g. youtube-dl runs it's downloads, where the download is called `file.part` until it's done, then it's renamed to `file.avi`. Is there a gstreamer plugin I'm not aware of that is doing this kind of conversion?

Comment: This seems like a poor fit for gstreamer. Why not just use a bash command that renames the file when the gstreamer command is done? `gst-launch ... filesink location=tmp.mp4 && mv tmp.mp4 my-video-file-processed.mp4`

Comment: Because a pipeline might process multiple files at once. When using the bindings, I could of course try to catch files that are done around the pipeline and rename them, but that appears to be hacky to me. I think the most canonical way is to have the renaming done as part of the pipeline

Comment: No, it is not hacky. Renaming/moving files are clearly application's duty.

Comment: NGL, I can see how the file handling is the applications' duty. Nevertheless, I still think renaming the file you're streaming into once it's done is pretty canonical and would most probably be used a lot. I'll accept this nielsdg's answer though, because gstreamer probably does not have such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no GStreamer element for what you're looking for because it's not really multimedia-related, so writing a GStreamer element for it would be overkill.

There's multiple things you can do here, but an obvious solution would be to have your pipeline end with  `... ! filesink location=my-video-file-process.mp4.temp`. Then, once the pipeline has ended, to rename the file programmatically from `my-video-file-process.mp4.temp` to `my-video-file-process.mp4`

Comment: Hmm, the obvious problem with this solution is that a pipeline might  process many files or run indefinately. It's not exactly obvious when a file is done being processed. Clearly, I could write a script checking when a file does not increase in size anymore and its size is > 0, but that does appear hacky to me.

Comment: Your remark is not specific to this answer though, but rather what you see (a part of) the pipeline as "finished". Note that when you're processing multiple files, you're already keeping track of which files you're writing to (so also which ones you should be renaming away from `.temp`. Depending on the media you're processing, that would be an EOS message for example. What would the expected behavior even be on a "indefinitely running" pipeline?